# Autolayout: y position of label is width of superview

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout

Example-
If on iphone 5(resolution 320x568), the label should be placed at 320(y position)

Comment: what is your question?

Comment: What constraint should I add to do this

Comment: Please check this document for how to ask question : http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This would be easy to do in code. You can add the constraint and set its `constant` to `UIScreen.mainScreen().size.width`.

Using Interface Builder, I would first add a helper view, setting its top, left and right constraint to `0` and setting its aspect constraint to `1:1`. That means that on a screen with width 320 the view frame would be `(0, 0, 320, 320)`.

Now you can position your view depending on the bottom of the helper view.

Answer (score 0):

You have to define Top Constraint as 320 px.

Using code -

```
[self.button addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self.view attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop relatedBy:0 toItem:self.view attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop multiplier:1 constant:320]];
```

Autolayout from storyboard [here](http://enharmonichq.com/tutorial-auto-layout-part-1/)

Comment: But it is 320 only on iphone 5, it will be different for other devices.

Answer (score 0):

In swift language, you can use it like that

```
let leftConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: self.label, 
                                   attribute: .Top, 
                                   relatedBy: 0,
                                      toItem: self.view,
                                   attribute: .Top, 
                                  multiplier: 1.0, 
                                    constant: 320.0);

self.view.addConstraint(leftConstraint);
```

Comment: But it is 320 only on iphone 5, it will be different for other devices.

Comment: you can find more details [here](http://makeapppie.com/2014/07/26/the-swift-swift-tutorial-how-to-use-uiviews-with-auto-layout-programmatically/)

Answer (score 0):

Add your constraint to label this way:

If you want it as programatically you can do it this way

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    
    let label  = UILabel()
    label.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
    label.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.Center
    label.text = "I'am a test label"
    label.setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints(false)
    view.addSubview(label)
    
    let horizontalConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: label, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.TrailingMargin, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: view, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.TrailingMargin, multiplier: 1, constant: 16)
    view.addConstraint(horizontalConstraint)
    
    let verticalConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: label, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Bottom, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: topLayoutGuide, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Bottom, multiplier: 1, constant: 50)
    view.addConstraint(verticalConstraint)
    
    let widthConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: label, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Width, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: nil, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.NotAnAttribute, multiplier: 1, constant: 150)
    label.addConstraint(widthConstraint)

    
    let heightConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: label, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Height, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: nil, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.NotAnAttribute, multiplier: 1, constant: 20)
    label.addConstraint(heightConstraint)
}
```

And if you don't want to set it programatically you can do it this way:

Select your label from storyBoard go to pin menu and add this constraint to it as shown in below Image:

[image]

Remember right side must set to 0 if you want that label at max y position of view.

Hope it will help.